# Distribution of Sum of Discrete Uniform Random Variables

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, statistical-inference

I just had a quick question that I hope someone can answer.
 Does anyone know what the distribution of the sum of discrete uniform random variables is?
 Is it a normal distribution?

Thanks!

Comment: First we want to specify that the discrete uniforms are independent and over the same interval. The sum is not normal, but the sum of a largish number of them is close enough to normal for most practical uses.

Comment: So if I have a sample of n discrete uniforms, that would be close enough to normal for the purposes of finding a complete statistic?

Comment: If you look up the defintion of complete statistic, you will find that the answer is no. In particular, for complete statistic the thing would have to woek for a sample of, say, $3$, where normal approximation is really not good.

Comment: Crap...alright, I guess I am back to the drawing board on this one then.

Comment: I don;t have time to give an answer, but for example if we are looking at the **continuous** uniform family in the interval $[0,\theta]$ where $\theta$ is a parameter, then the **maximum** of the $n$ observations is a complete statistic. This should be even more true for a similar family, discrete uniform on the interval $[0,\theta]$ where the parameter $\theta$ is an integer.

Comment: The drawing board is always a good place to start. One wonders who upvoted this question?

Answer (score 9):

The distribution is asymptotically normal. Otherwise, the exact distribution is that of a normalized extended binomial coefficient, see "Polynomial Coefficients and Distribution of the Sum of Discrete Uniform Variables" by Camila C. S. Caiado and Pushpa N. Rathie at http://community.dur.ac.uk/c.c.d.s.caiado/multinomial.pdf.

Comment: This explanation seems to be more approachable: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf

Comment: For later reference (in case of 404 errors), the URL to the full book Introduction to Probability by Charles M. Grinstead and J. Laurie Snell is http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html

Comment: Hi Casey and Ludovic, Thanks for your information. I can find the paper written by Camila  and Pushpa. But I still get confused about Polynomial Coefficient, expecially how to calculate it. May I ask how to calculate the Polynomial Coefficient by using software, say R or Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

So, the idea is to iteratively calculate PMF, using sum of $n-1$ variables to derive PMF of the sum of $n$ variables.

$$P_{a, b, n}(x) = \sum_{i \in a..b} P_{a, b, 1}(i) * P_{a, b, n-1}(x-i)$$

where $P_{a,b,n}$ is the PMF of the sum of $n$ discrete uniform variables.

Notional Python code to calculate the coefficients can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791287).