# Does the sequence $n_i = n_{i-1} + random(a, b)$ have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, random, random-walk

I'm interested in the sequence $n_i = n_{i-1} + random(a, b)$ or, in plain English, "the next number is equal to the previous number plus a random quantity between a and b (for example $a=-1, b=1$)".

I'd like to read more about these sequences but I don't know how they're called, if they have a name at all, and how to search for them.

Comment: The term "random walk" comes to mind, try searching for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's two cases to consider: is $\operatorname{random}(a,b)$ a discrete random variable equal to one of the values $\{a, a+1, \dots,b\}$ with equal probability, or a continuous random variable equal to a uniformly chosen real number in $[a,b]$?

In the first case, see a previous question: [Distribution of Sum of Discrete Uniform Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357442/distribution-of-sum-of-discrete-uniform-random-variables).

In the second case, we can normalize, defining $n_i' = \frac{n_i - ai}{b-a}$, which will now satisfy the recurrence $n_i' = n_{i-1}' + \operatorname{random}(0,1)$. This is known as the [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) or just the "uniform sum distribution".